# Sql query to retrieve all records along with relation ordered by foreign key with Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have 2 tables named as 'genre' and 'preferred_genre', there is a foreign key in 'preferred_genre' table as 'genre_id' and it also have a 'user_id' column, i want to retrieve all the genre's but first those genre which has foreign key relation in 'preferred_genre' table, and is preferred by the logged in user.

> genre -> id,genre_name
>
> preferred_genre ->id, genre_id, user_id

```
# genre table #
===============
id | genre_name 
---------------
1  | action    
2  | comedy
3  | horror
4  | drama

# preferred_genre table #
=========================
id | genre_id | user_id 
------------------------
1  |     2    |   5
2  |     4    |   5
3  |     1    |   8
4  |     4    |   8
```

let the logged in user id is 5

```
$q = Genre::select('genres.*');
$q->leftJoin('preferred_genres', function($join)
{
   $join->on('genres.id', '=', 'preferred_genres.genre_id');
   $join->where('user_id','=',Auth::id());
});
$genre_list = $q->orderBy('preferred_genres.created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

I want to get all the genres but the genre preferred by user_id 5, first, followed by all other genre, as follows

```
id  | genre_name
----------------
2   | comedy
4   | drama
1   | action
3   | horror
```

Comment: Please include a clear expected output along with an explanation of why you expect it to appear that way.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , I have updated the output

Comment: i posted an answer but take a note you already    $join->where('user_id','=',Auth::id()); so this query will only get the preferred but logged in user only but will order them by the preferred by user 5 then the rest of logged in user

Answer (score 0):

```
$q->orderByRaw("FIELD(preferred_genres.user_id, 5) ASC");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $list=DB::table('genres')
       ->select('genres.*','preferred_genres.*')
       ->join('preferred_genres','genres.id', '=','preferred_genres.genre_id')
       ->where('genres.user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)
       ->orderBy('preferred_genres.created_at', 'DESC')
       ->get();
```